# Unable to read input file '/Users/anonymous/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, info.plist

This message just appeared out of nowhere even though I made absolutely no changes to the project.  I have an Ionic cordova project that has been working for Android and iOS.  The project builds fine in Visual Studio code for ios but when I open the project in xCode then I try to run the emulator in xCode I get the following error message:

Showing All Messages
unable to read input file '/Users/anonymous/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist': fopen(/Users/anonymous/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist, rb): Operation not permitted (1)

This is really weird because I haven't changed anything in the project so I'm not sure why it's trying to copy the .plist file from the downloads folder even though I've added it to the root project and the project\platforms\ios directory.

I found one solution that suggested adding the following to my config.xml:

That did not work.  It actually caused build failures within Visual Studio Code.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.  I'm not sure why this would issue would appear all of a sudden and the solutions I've seen online haven't been helpful.

I can see the .plist file in xCode
[image]

Comment: Have you already tried deleting the iOS project from the `platform` folder and adding the platform (and building the app) again?

Comment: That's a last resort.  Deleting and re-adding the platform has so many other headaches with the plugins as well.  If I can't find anything online then I'll try that last @sebaferreras

Comment: Ideally if the dependencies in the package.json file are correct nothing should be broken when doing that (I delete the platforms before preparing each release for example) but yeah, I understand that it may cause more harm than good. Have you tried searching for "GoogleService-Info.plist" in the native iOS project files to see if that file is referenced by mistake from the download folder in any of the "native" files?

Comment: removed and re-added the project worked.  Thanks @sebaferreras

Comment: Glad to hear that!